# Has fdformat been excluded from the latest util-linux package?

Tags: package-management, aws

I'm using Ubuntu 5.15.0-1011-aws.
When I run the following command in Ubuntu

```
$fdformat --version
```

It outputs the following:

```
Command 'fdformat' not found, .....
```

Since fdformat is in util-linux as I searched on linux manual page, I run the following command:

```
$apt info util-linux
```

It returns:

```
...
Package: util-linux
Version: 2.37.2-4ubuntu3
.....
```

Then I check the info of util-linux package on my machine,

```
$ sudo apt upgrade util-linux
```

It shows the following:

```
...
util-linux is already the newest version (2.37.2-4ubuntu3).
...
```

My question is whether fdformat has been excluded from the latest package of util-linux?

Answer (score 5):

It was removed from the default build of `util-linux` by the developers of `util-linux`. See commit [`13b26e3c36d110b4e372f93762e25fc40c94d9e0`](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/13b26e3c36d110b4e372f93762e25fc40c94d9e0):

> #### fdformat: remove command from default build
>
> It should be safe assumption a command related to floppy disks does
> not need to be part of default build.  Notice that the reference
> commit removed floppy driver from linux about year ago.  Virtual
> floppies might exist they should not need low-level formatting.  But
> if someone really needs this enabling the build in that case is better
> than pushing the binary by default to many many systems that install
> util-linux.
>
> Reference: [`torvalds/linux@47d6a76`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/47d6a7607443ea43dbc4d0f371bf773540a8f8f4)

(The kernel commit referred to actually marked the driver as *orphaned*.)

Answer (score 0):

@li_jessen What you can do to use fdformat, or other utils that depend on it like KFloppy (which is still in the repos), is download the latest version of util-linux that has it, from focal fossa (20.04), then extract the .deb, and then extract the data.tar.xz inside. Inside there, in usr/sbin, is fdformat. I just ran sudo cp fdformat /usr/sbin, and now everything works perfectly fine with my USB floppy drive. I tested this on a core 2 duo system with a real floppy drive and it also worked well. Since fdformat doesnt depend on or affect other binaries in the util-linux package, and you are not overwriting anything (since it doesnt even exist in newer util-linux packages), you will not screw anything up, and if it doesnt work for you or you want to remove it, just delete it. You could also make a copy directly in /sbin if you want some busybox apps to use it.

Here is a direct link to the latest util-linux from focal fossa that has it > [util-linux_2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/util-linux_2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3_amd64.deb)

(Some links from the ubuntu package search act weird in the latest chromium based browsers. Just clicking on it will open a tab that closes itself. You might have to copy the link, and manually paste it into a new tab and press enter to get it to download, I have had to do this when downloading individual .debs from archive.ubuntu.org or security.ubuntu.org.)